# I am working on a java Web application.In which i have to show contact detail.used framework is struts 1.3

Tags: java

I am working on a Struts 1.3 project, 
I am working on a jsp page in which many links exist and requirement is, if user click any link then ,I have a huge amount of data returned from the calls,i want to display returned data in a table using Display tag in same jsp div element.
and page size of table is 10.
Using Ajax is  a way to do that.Can any one explain me how can i do that.
I can display returned  data on another page  after clicking on links using display tag.
but i can't get way to show returned data on same page using display tag

Thank you

Comment: You will have to write some JavaScript code to achieve that.

Comment: can you explain me steps

Comment: ok now i have done it